# rbenv can not install ruby

Tags: ruby, rbenv

When I want to use `rbenv install ruby 2.0.0` in my computer with Ubuntu 14.04. It causes  the error below:

```
$ rbenv install 2.0.0-p247
Downloading yaml-0.1.6.tar.gz...
-> http://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/7da6971b4bd08a986dd2a61353bc422362bd0edcc67d7ebaac68c95f74182749
Installing yaml-0.1.6...
Installed yaml-0.1.6 to /home/grant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247

Downloading ruby-2.0.0-p247.tar.gz...
-> http://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/3e71042872c77726409460e8647a2f304083a15ae0defe90d8000a69917e20d3
Installing ruby-2.0.0-p247...

BUILD FAILED

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20140607140231.15470
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20140607140231.15470.log

Last 10 log lines:
compiling ossl_hmac.c
compiling ossl_x509store.c
compiling ossl_pkcs12.c
compiling ossl_pkey_dh.c
compiling ossl_x509name.c
installing default openssl libraries
linking shared-object openssl.so
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/ruby-build.20140607140231.15470/ruby-2.0.0-p247/ext/openssl'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/ruby-build.20140607140231.15470/ruby-2.0.0-p247'
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
```

I have confirmed I have installed `openssl`, `libssl1.0.0`, `libssl-dev` packages. How can I fix it?

Comment: Do other versions work?

Comment: Checkout all dependencies there https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.04#ruby

Comment: 1.9.3 can be installed successful but 2.0.0, 2.1.0 both install fail.

Comment: @dubadub thanks, just install it by this guide but still install fail.

Answer (score 0):

It is caused by difference in ReadLine naming. Install 2.1.2 or you need to patch your installation: https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build/issues/526

Answer (score 0):

As another user mentioned, the issue seems to be happening with readline and can be fixed by reinstalling the package.

```
brew uninstall readline
brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew/0181c8a1633353affefabe257c170edbd6d7c008/Library/Formula/readline.rb
brew pin readline
```